# How to Keep Alive SNMP agent

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I succcesfully created SNMP agent using snmp4j libraray 
Here is the refrence [code](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/creating-snmp-agent-server-in-java-using-snmp4j/).

My query is how can i make this agent to run always to listen all incoming OIDs from manager.??

Comment: Is your question related to background processes/daemons in general as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process or do you have something SNMP specific in mind ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public synchronized void listen() throws IOException
      {
         TransportIpAddress address2=  new UdpAddress(2069);
        AbstractTransportMapping transport;
        if (address2 instanceof TcpAddress)
        {
          transport = new DefaultTcpTransportMapping((TcpAddress) address2);
        }
        else
        {
         //  transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping( (UdpAddress) address2);
               transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        }

        ThreadPool threadPool = ThreadPool.create("DispatcherPool", 10);
        MessageDispatcher mtDispatcher = new MultiThreadedMessageDispatcher(threadPool, new MessageDispatcherImpl());

        // add message processing models
        mtDispatcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv1());
        mtDispatcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c());

        // add all security protocols
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addDefaultProtocols();
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new Priv3DES());

        //Create Target
        CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
        target.setCommunity( new OctetString("password"));

        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(mtDispatcher, transport);
        snmp.addCommandResponder(this);

        transport.listen();
        System.out.println("Listening on " + address);

        try
        {
          this.wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
```